# Fetch thousand of files from S3/minio with a single page webapp (no server)

Tags: reactjs, ajax, amazon-s3, minio

I'm developing a single page app for image annotation. Each .jpg file is stored on S3/minIO services, coupled with a .xml file (Pascal VOC notation), which describes the coordinates and positions for each annotation associated to the image.

I'd like to fetch all the xml data, to be able filtering my image results within the webapp project (based upon ReactJS). But thousand of request to an S3 server directly from a web app seems a bit odd to me; nevertheless, I would prefer avoid using any "middleware" servers (like python/flask or nodejs), relying on the ReactJS app.

I've not been able to find any workaround to download all the xml files content with a single ajax call; do you have some idea to address this kind of issue?

Comment: What have you found or tried already?

Comment: Hi @macborowy, I'm fetching the data via listObjectsV2, and downloading each xml file (some thousand) with getObject. after some hundred request they all start to fail

Comment: (the issue that I've got in the Chrome console on failed calls is net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES)

Answer (score 0):

The S3 API doesn't provide an API to fetch multiple files in a single operation. As you have suggested in your question,  your application will need to handle this logic by first getting a list of the objects then iterating through that list.

Alternatively, if you can consider storing the xml files as a single archive.